# Non-positive metric on a product is a product metric

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have heard mentioned the following theorem:

If a Riemannian metric on a product of two Riemann surfaces has non-positive sectional curvature then the metric is a product metric.

And am trying to find a reference for it but have not found anything, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very special case of Theorem 10.3.9 in Eberlein's book "Geometry of nonpositively curved manifolds".